# Building Yocto image for DragonBoard 410c, how to build Chromium

Tags: linux, chromium, yocto, dragonboard

How to generate an image with Sato and Chromium for the [DragonBoard 410c](https://developer.qualcomm.com/hardware/dragonboard-410c)?

Starting from the [qcom-oe-manifest](https://github.com/ndechesne/qcom-oe-manifest) referred in the [Dragonboard-410c-OpenEmbedded-and-Yocto documentation](https://github.com/96boards/documentation/wiki/Dragonboard-410c-OpenEmbedded-and-Yocto)

What is the correct/proper way to add Sato desktop and Chromium to this base config?

What's I have done:

- Added `x11-base x11-sato` to **IMAGE_FEATURES**
- Added `chromium alsa-utils lsb` to **CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL**

### my-image.bb

```
/oe-qcom-yocto/sources$ more ./meta-rpb/recipes-samples/images/my-image.bb

SUMMARY = "Basic console image"

IMAGE_FEATURES += "x11-base x11-sato splash package-management ssh-server-dropbear hwcodecs"

LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image distro_features_check extrausers

# let's make sure we have a good image..
REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "pam systemd"

CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += " \
    chromium alsa-utils lsb \
    coreutils gptfdisk kernel-modules connman 96boards-tools \
"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
useradd -p '' linaro; \
"
```

Then running `bitbake -v`

### chromium was skipped: incompatible with machine dragonboard-410c

```
~/oe-qcom-yocto/build-jethro$  bitbake -v my-image


NOTE: Started PRServer with DBfile: /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build-jethro/cache/prserv.sqlite3, IP: 127.0.0.1, PORT: 51063, PID: 1432
Loading cache: 100% |############################################################################################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 2948 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
NOTE: selecting pigz-native to satisfy gzip-native due to PREFERRED_PROVIDERS
NOTE: selecting pseudo-native to satisfy virtual/fakeroot-native due to PREFERRED_PROVIDERS
NOTE: selecting linux-linaro-qcomlt to satisfy virtual/kernel due to PREFERRED_PROVIDERS
NOTE: selecting opkg-native to satisfy opkg-native due to PREFERRED_PROVIDERS
NOTE: selecting opkg-utils-native to satisfy virtual/update-alternatives-native due to PREFERRED_PROVIDERS
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'chromium' (but /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build-jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-rpb/recipes-samples/images/my-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: chromium was skipped: incompatible with machine dragonboard-410c (not in COMPATIBLE_MACHINE)
NOTE: Runtime target 'chromium' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['chromium']
NOTE: Target 'my-image' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['my-image', 'chromium']
ERROR: Required build target 'my-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['my-image', 'chromium']

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

### Added `dragonboard-410c` to `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` - new ERROR

```
...
NOTE: selecting gettext to satisfy virtual/gettext due to PREFERRED_PROVIDERS
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libav' (but /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build-jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium_40.0.2214.91.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: libav was skipped: because it has a restricted license not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
NOTE: Target 'libav' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['libav']
NOTE: Runtime target 'chromium' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['chromium', 'libav']
NOTE: Target 'my-image' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['my-image', 'chromium', 'libav']
ERROR: Required build target 'my-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['my-image', 'chromium', 'libav']
```

### UPDATE

Added `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial"` at the end of `build_jethro/conf/local.conf` file and it's building my image

#### ERROR: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://include.gypi anywhere.

```
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL file://include.gypi, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://include.gypi anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-40.0.2214.91/rpb
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/rpb
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/files/rpb
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-40.0.2214.91/aarch64
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/aarch64
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/files/aarch64
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-40.0.2214.91/dragonboard-410c
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/dragonboard-410c
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/files/dragonboard-410c
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-40.0.2214.91/aarch64
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/aarch64
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/files/aarch64
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium-40.0.2214.91/
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/files/
    /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/sources/downloads
ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL: 'file://include.gypi'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/tmp-rpb-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/chromium/40.0.2214.91-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.10845
ERROR: Task 197 (/home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/conf/../../sources/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium_40.0.2214.91.bb, do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

`include.gypi` in the Chromium recipe

```
joel@linux-Lenovo-G50-70:~/oe-qcom-yocto/sources$ grep -r "include.gypi" *
meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium_40.0.2214.91.bb:        file://include.gypi \
meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium_40.0.2214.91.bb: -I ${WORKDIR}/include.gypi \
```

#### Added `aarch64`

Created `meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/aarch64` folder and added `include.gypi` and `oe-defaults.gypi` as recommended by LightenS

include.gypi

```
meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/aarch64$ more include.gypi

{
  'variables': {
    'target_arch': 'arm64',
    'use_allocator': 0,
    'use_xkbcommon': 1,
     'v8_use_external_startup_data' : 0,
     'v8_use_snapshot' : 'false',
  }, 
}
```

oe-defaults.gypi

```
meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/aarch64$ more oe-defaults.gypi

{
  'variables': {
    'use_system_bzip2': 1,
    'disable_nacl': 1,
    'proprietary_codecs': 1,
    'v8_use_snapshot': 1,
    'ffmpeg_branding' : 'Chrome',
    'use_system_ffmpeg': 0,
    'linux_link_kerberos': 0,
    'use_kerberos': 0,
    'use_cups': 0,
    'use_gnome_keyring': 0,
    'linux_link_gnome_keyring': 0
  }, 
}
```

### NEW Issue

```
 [301/16647] CXX obj/breakpad/src/client/linux/minidump_writer/breakpad_client.linux_ptrace_dumper.o
| 
| [301/16647] CXX obj/breakpad/src/client/linux/minidump_writer/breakpad_client.linux_ptrace_dumper.o
| FAILED: aarch64-oe-linux-g++  --sysroot=/home/joel/oe-qcom-yocto/build_jethro/tmp-rpb-glibc/sysroots/dragonboard-410c -MMD -MF obj/breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/breakpad_client.thread_info.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNO_TCMALLOC -DDISABLE_NACL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DUSE_XI2_MT=2 -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DUSE_PROPRIETARY_CODECS -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DCLD2_DATA_SOURCE=static -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_MANAGED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DENABLE_LOAD_COMPLETION_HACKS=1 -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -Igen -I../../breakpad/src -I../../breakpad/src/client -I../../breakpad/src/third_party/linux/include -I../.. -I../../breakpad -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -Wno-error=unused-local-typedefs -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-deprecated -std=gnu++11 -Wno-narrowing -Wno-literal-suffix  -c ../../breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.cc -o obj/breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/breakpad_client.thread_info.o
| In file included from ../../breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.cc:30:0:
| ../../breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.h:69:23: error: field 'regs' has incomplete type 'google_breakpad::user_pt_regs'
|    struct user_pt_regs regs;
|                        ^
| ../../breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.h:69:10: note: forward declaration of 'struct google_breakpad::user_pt_regs'
|    struct user_pt_regs regs;
|           ^
| ../../breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.h:70:28: error: field 'fpregs' has incomplete type 'google_breakpad::user_fpsimd_state'
|    struct user_fpsimd_state fpregs;
|                             ^
| ../../breakpad/src/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.h:70:10: note: forward declaration of 'struct google_breakpad::user_fpsimd_state'
|    struct user_fpsimd_state fpregs;
|
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a Sato package in Openembedded-core you could inherit to [HERE](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-sato/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-x11-sato.bb)

If you want to build Sato image, there are a list here from Openembedded-core [HERE](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-sato/images)

From [chromium.inc](https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser/blob/master/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium.inc), Chromium does not support the board you have. Which is `Quad-core ARM® Cortex® A53`, You could try to add the machine to the list and compile. Your machine should be [aarch64](https://github.com/ndechesne/meta-qcom/blob/master/conf/machine/dragonboard-410c.conf)

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "(-)"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_x86 = "(.*)"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_x86-64 = "(.*)"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_armv6 = "(.*)"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_armv7a = "(.*)"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_aarch64 = "(.*)"
```

**Edit**: Chromium requires the following to be compiled;

`DEPENDS = "xz-native pciutils pulseaudio cairo nss zlib-native libav cups ninja-native gconf libexif pango libdrm"`

`DEPENDS += "libgnome-keyring"`

In those dependencies, `libav` needs to be WHITELISTED. To do this, we need to go to `conf/local.conf` and add `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial"`.

[Click Here, and look for Section 12.5](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) to know more about License.

---

**Edit**: Fetcher Issue:
You will need `include.gypi` and `oe-defaults.gypi` files added to `/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium/aarch64/`

`chromium/chromium/aarch64/include.gypi`

```
{
  'variables': {
    'target_arch': 'arm64',
    'use_allocator': 0,
    'use_xkbcommon': 1,
     'v8_use_external_startup_data' : 0,
     'v8_use_snapshot' : 'false',
  }, 
}
```

`chromium/chromium/oe-defaults.gypi`

```
{
  'variables': {
    'use_system_bzip2': 1,
    'disable_nacl': 1,
    'proprietary_codecs': 1,
    'v8_use_snapshot': 1,
    'ffmpeg_branding' : 'Chrome',
    'use_system_ffmpeg': 0,
    'linux_link_kerberos': 0,
    'use_kerberos': 0,
    'use_cups': 0,
    'use_gnome_keyring': 0,
    'linux_link_gnome_keyring': 0
  }, 
}
```

**Edit:** The Correct meta-browser for the dragonboard should be this : https://github.com/kuscsik/meta-browser-1.  Inside, there is all the files required for the board.

Comment: Added the machine to COMPATIBLE_MACHINE and I am getting now `ERROR: libav was skipped: because it has a restricted license not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` . See UPDATE in the question

Comment: In local.conf. add `LICENSE_FLAG_WHITELIST = "commercial" ` and libav should be able to build

Comment: That works. Note the minor tipo LICENSE_FLAG**S**_WHITELIST = "commercial". Now getting `ERROR: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://include.gypi anywhere.`. I wonder if I should change the manifest to use `<remote fetch="git://github.com/linaro-home" name="browser-layer"/>` instead

Comment: you could take a look at example: common.gypi for chromium.  It shows the configuration of chromium. https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/build/common.gypi

Comment: Ok I have added `armv8/include.gypi` and  `armv8/oe-defaults.gypi`. but I am still getting the same error. I tried looking the Chromium recipe see if I should adjust a path for the WORKDIR ... I am not certain it's actually fetching from the `armv8`. May I have missed something else? (See updated Question for my input)

Comment: Could you try to throw those 2 files to `/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium`?  We would not use the armv8 directory.

Comment: I am looking at where they called those files based on the machine architecture.

Comment: Ok it worked, but I have now another issue :( feel free to update your answer thought. It was valuable. Now updating my question with the new issue

Comment: I am now getting `aarch64-oe-linux-g++: error: unrecognized command line option` ...  making some progress though.

Comment: could you add the 2 lines  `'armv7' : 0,`  and `'arm_neon' : 0,` to `include.gypi`?  It is using the armv7 architecture to compile.  `-Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -march=armv7-a -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107583/discussion-between-joel-and-lightens).